# Can’t position Gradient Texture on Object (eyeball) properly

Tags: node-editor

Every time I try to center the light in the middle of the eye like in the tutorial, it doesn't work and ends up centering around where I put the mark seam.
It's supposed to look like this:

[image]

But turns out like this:

[image]

If anyone knows what's wrong and can help me I'd really appreciate it. Thanks, tutorial's linked below if that helps.

www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0JyyWeptSA

And here's my blend file:
[image]

Comment: Okay. I'll remember that for the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is position of UV map.

Tutorial (and you) are using UV texture coordinates, but your UV map is not placed in center of "UV Editor". Since you move the front part of eye in a center it matches.

[image]

BTW instead of UV I would rather use Texture Coordinates

type Generated (Loc -0.5 / -0.5 / -1)

[image]

or easier type Object (Loc 0 / 0 / -1)

[image]

Comment: This worked, thanks so much for the help and tips. :)

Comment: If answer helped, consider to mark answer as correct by clicking on check mark (under vote arrow) to let know others (with similar issue) this was solved for you (visible from Q list too). Thanks